# What security properties were required by NIST on the SHA3 project?

Tags: hash

From [this link](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/hash-functions/sha-3-project), NIST claims that:

> A cryptographic hash algorithm (alternatively, hash "function") is designed to provide a random mapping from a string of binary data to a fixed-size “message digest” and achieve certain security properties. (...) As a result of these workshops, NIST decided to develop a new cryptographic hash algorithm for standardization through a public competition.

What security properties were the participants of the competition required to prove about their constructions? Could you point to the right link?

Comment: Here's [NIST's original 2007 call for submissions](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2007/11/02/E7-21581/announcing-request-for-candidate-algorithm-nominations-for-a-new-cryptographic-hash-algorithm-sha-3), which goes into qute a bit of detail.

Comment: @LuisCasillas thanks for finding it. You could've posted it as an answer.